# What wire size do i use for a 100 amp sub panel

Tags: subpanel

I am adding a 100 amp sub panel off the 100 amp main breaker. Don't understand the directions on what wire size to use. I bought the PowerMark Gold 100 Amp 32-Space 32-Circuit Indoor Main Breaker Circuit Breaker Panel. I was going to use a #6 stranded wire for for ground and 3 #3 stranded wire. Is this correct?

Comment: Copper or aluminum wires? Is this subpanel coming off of lugs from the main panel? Or off of a separate breaker in the main panel?

Comment: Is this panel in the same structure/building as the panel it's being fed from, or off in a different building/structure?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're speaking of individual wires, that installation will need to be inside properly installed conduit, that is built 100% complete before any wires are pulled in.  It must be constructed to be "pullable" and necessary access points must remain accessible (e.g. not mudded over or buried).

For heavy feeder like this, copper is a waste of money since the lugs are made of aluminum anyway, and "whether you used a torque wrench" is much, much more important to safety than the metal of the wire.   I only use it when forced to owing to existing conduit being of limited size.

#3 copper with a #8 ground will suffice for 100A.
#1 aluminum with #6 insulated ground will suffice for 100A.
Many people find #2 aluminum is a more readily available commodity item; that is good to 90A. Many people they either pick the "100A" number out of thin air because it is nice and round, or think that since the panel has a hard redline "never exceed" rating of 100A, therefore they must run 100A wire to it.  Not at all; the wire need merely <= the panel.

In fact, on that subject, don't let yourself ever run out of breaker spaces.  Spaces are cheap, regrets are expensive, and 100A is A LOT of power.  So think big and get lots of circuit breaker spaces. A few dollars there is a much wiser investment than copper wire.

Comment: The one catch with 90A #1 aluminum: If the 100A feed is *not* a separate breaker but rather off lugs from the main panel (i.e., protected by the 100A main breaker) then it has to be 100A rated wire. Except *maybe* it would then get the same "whole service" derate that the main feed into the main panel gets and therefore #2 aluminum OK?

Comment: @manassehkatz yeah 310.15(B)(7) needs no feeder off a service needs to be bigger than the service wire needs to be.

Comment: So then really the only time 100A on 2 AWG aluminum would be a problem is if the main feed is 200A (or really anything > 100A) **and** no separate 90A breaker or smaller for that feeder. "100A main breaker" implies "100A feed" and should be fine.

Comment: @manassehkats yes, but for the classic "100A subpanel" (off a larger panel) that's all the time.  The sub wiring can only be #2 if the weatherhead-to-meter wiring is allowed to be #2.

Comment: Agreed. The real question, which we don't know, is whether OP's feed is actually 100A utility -> 100A main panel or if there are other things going on.